# Material UI: Why does my select update the state, but not display the selected value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

As many of my select options are very similar to each other, I tried to create a single component for them. I read that I have to forward the refs, so I did this, and now I do not have any error messages anymore and my state is being updated correctly after the selection.

The only thing which does not update is the select field, which always display empty.

**Dropdown.js**

```
import { Select } from "@material-ui/core";
import CustomOption from "./CustomOption";

class Dropdown extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      selection: 0
    };
  }

  handleChange = name => event => {
    console.log(event.target.value);
    switch (name) {
      // More cases
      default:
        this.setState({ [name]: event.target.value });
        break;
    }
  };

  render = () => {
    return (
      <>
        <Select
          value={this.state.selection}
          onChange={this.handleChange("selection")}
        >
          <CustomOption text="A" value={0} testValue={2} />
          <CustomOption text="B" value={1} testValue={2} />
          <CustomOption text="C" value={2} testValue={1} />
          <CustomOption text="D" value={3} testValue={2} />
        </Select>
        <br />
        <br />
        {this.state.selection}
      </>
    );
  };
}

export default Dropdown;
```

**CustomOption.js**

```
import React from "react";
import { ListItemText, MenuItem } from "@material-ui/core";

const DropdownEntry = React.forwardRef((props, ref) => {
  if (props["data-value"] > props.testValue) {
    return (
      <MenuItem disabled ref={ref} {...props}>
        <ListItemText>{props.text}</ListItemText>
      </MenuItem>
    );
  }

  // User may select this option
  return (
    <MenuItem ref={ref} {...props}>
      <ListItemText>{props.text}</ListItemText>
    </MenuItem>
  );
});

export default DropdownEntry;
```

Codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/us4ml

Comment: I suspect it's because you're nesting arrow functions here: `handleChange = name => event => {`

Comment: I'm getting a big 'ol error on your codesandbox:  sandbox.115b0c69.js:1 Warning: React does not recognize the `testValue` prop on a DOM element. If you intentionally want it to appear in the DOM as a custom attribute, spell it as lowercase `testvalue` instead. If you accidentally passed it from a parent component, remove it from the DOM element.

Comment: Other than that - it seems to work.  I see the index of the selected item in the static field every time I use the drop down

Comment: Why are you nesting a `CustomOption` instead of native `MenuItem`?

Comment: Whoops, testvalue throws indeed errors. Well, besides from this error it seems to work. BUT, the value selected is not being displayed inside the dropdown field. Lets say I select B, I would like to see B as selected without clicking the dropdown  again.

Comment: This is only a minimal example which reproduces my problem. The real one has way more props and logic, and is used about 200x in my project. This is why I would like to put it in another component.